# How to make dataframe from complex json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data as json below. I want to convert it to dataframe that I can export to **excel**. However, I can't find a way to make correct dataframe. I attached example of dataframe below. I am using **Pandas** but I can  use any other library also.

```
{
   "Street1":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   },
   "Street2":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   },
   "Street3":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the JSON file using builtin [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). It will create a dictionary from the JSON data. Then convert the dictionary to CSV file using Pandas [`to_csv` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#).

Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


data = json.load(open("data.json"))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

`data.json`:

```
{
   "Street1":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   },
   "Street2":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   },
   "Street3":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   }
}
```

**Output:**

`output.csv`:

```
,a,b,c
Street1,1,2,3
Street2,1,2,3
Street3,1,2,3
```

**References:**

- [Documentation on `json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- [Documentation on `to_csv` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df).T.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns= {'index':'s_name'})
df.to_excel('dataframe.xlsx', index=False)
```